# Python Kivy: garden install command fails "no attribute '__file__'"

Tags: python, kivy

Good morning folks,

I followed all the instructions to the best of my knowledge for the installation of Kivy.

Unfortunately, after all the setup is complete, I am unable to install a module using `garden`, which is what I need to do to get `Kivy-Designer`.

Please advise if you know what I need to do and where I went wrong. 
See the link below for a screenshot.

[image]

Thanks!

-V

Answer (score 0):

Try to install kivy-garden-0.1.2 vesrion from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kivy-garden/0.1.2